# Disable shipping Method from frontend but not in backend

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping-methods

In Magento 1.x all shipping rates calculation done by a collect rate function

```
public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request) {
    if (!Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/' . $this->_code . '/active')) {
        return false;
    }
/*************** Start Logic to calculate rates****************/

/***************End Logic to calculate rates****************/

}
```

So if we want to hide that specific shipping method from the list in checkout page frontend. Then what is the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

**No need to add this code:**

```
if (!Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/' . $this->_code . '/active')) {
        return false;
    }
```

**just add this in place of above code.:**

```
if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
     }
```

**Disable for Frontend:**
Goto backend *admin>System>Configuratgion*
 and select your ***current scope*** to ***Main Website*** from Left panel of page

then goto **Sales>Shipping Methods** Select *your shipping method*  and make ***`Enabled=NO`***.

**For enable for admin:**

Goto backend *admin>System>Configuratgion*
 and select your ***current scope*** to ***Default configuration*** from Left panel of page

then goto **Sales>Shipping Methods** Select *your shipping method*  and make ***`Enabled=Yes`***.

### If it not work then

add  `if(!Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin())` return false; at start of the

*collectRates()* function

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method in your custom Module helper to check, It is in Admin area or frontend area. Like below:

```
class Namespace_Modulename_Helper_Isadmin extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
public function isAdmin()
{
    if(Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin())
    {
        return true;
    }

    if(Mage::getDesign()->getArea() == 'adminhtml')
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

And You can add below condition in shipping method `collectRates` or `getAllowedMethods` function to not show shipping method in frontend.

```
if( !Mage::helper('modulename/isadmin')->isAdmin() )
{
//do the thing in frontend
return false;
}
```

Frontend check code taken from alan answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693020/magento-request-frontend-or-backend